# How to count up all "TRUE" values from a column (of logical values) in a Data Frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, logical-operators

This is language R. Logical Values are in column 5. But, it doesn't seem to go through all of the values of the column. What's the easiest way of doing this?

```
count = 0

if (students[ , 5] == "TRUE") {
  count = count + 1
}

num_better_at_math = count
```

Comment: `sum(students[[5]])`

Comment: Thank you. Also, I am assuming the extra brackets were a typo?

Comment: No, actually. You can do `students[ , 5]` with a vanilla data.frame because `[.data.frame` has a default `drop = TRUE` parameter for single columns, but that doesn't hold for data frame variants like `tbl_df`, i.e. "tibbles". `[[` subsetting will work anywhere, as they're all lists underneath.

Comment: That's a bit confusing haha. What are tibbles and how are they different?

Comment: They're a tweaked version of a data.frame used by the tidyverse. [Here's a fuller explanation.](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed(1L)
df1 <- data.frame(a1 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5, TRUE),
                  a2 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5, TRUE),
                  a3 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5, TRUE),
                  a4 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5, TRUE),
                  a5 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5, TRUE))

colSums(df1)
# a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 
# 3  1  3  2  3

sum(df1[, 5])
# [1] 3
```